# Setting my own DKIM in Mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill, dkim

What do i need to send my emails with DKIM , but with my own DKIM signature and no via the 'authenticate this campaign' checkbox.

Mandrill offers a DKIM & SPF steps for setting but Mailchimp doesn't.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

When you select Mailchimp's checkbox option to authenticate campaign, Mailchimp is able to automatically attach authentication to your email campaigns without you setting up explicit approval on your server because if you look at the headers of the email when you send it, they are never really affiliating with your server. It will appear as though your campaign was sent from:

```
you@yoursite.com
```

But if you look closely at the headers of the email you will find something similar to FROM:

```
From: =?utf-8?Q?you?=you@yoursite.com
```

And the sender will say something like:

```
you=yoursite.com@mail94.us2.mcsv.net
```

So all of the authentication is set up by Mailchimp on Mailchimp's own outbound SMTP servers, there is never really any interaction with your server.. yoursite.com.

Thus, to answer your question, it's impossible to use your own DKIM signature and send your emails via Mailchimp because the emails would have be getting sent from your domain.. but they're not.. they're being sent from any number of hundreds of servers that Mailchimp owns.

Answer (score 0):

For DKIM, as David noted, you just need to enable their checkbox. If you want to use your own domain, and not showing **on behalf of**, then just update the SPF record that you have and their servers as allowed.

This will allow you to enable [DMARC](http://dmarc.org/) too.